# ODBC Bridge needed for JSON / RESTful web application

Tags: json, rest, odbc, sage-erp

I've been running in circles looking for a way to deliver data from a proprietary flat file database (based on the ProvideX platform) to a client-thick web application that makes RESTful requests and expects JSON responses.

ProvideX and Sage MAS 90 provided an ODBC driver that works for pulling tables, but I can't think of a good way to connect the dots without needing to program a bunch of server-side code.

Before I go down the path of programming custom server-side middleware, does anyone have any bright ideas, (or obvious ideas that I have overlooked)?

I am not locked into any particular architecture at the moment because we are hashing out requirements for the web application, so any ideas would be helpful.

ProvideX/Sage provides a web services module, but I can't use it because my company has refused to invest in the software module and upgrade costs. Let's not let that be a distraction, however, because I am still looking for a way to use the ODBC driver in this question thread.

Answer (score 0):

ODBC-ODBC Bridges exist but all the ones I know are commercial.